# Main-Class can't be set to existing class

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have a build setup that requires that my classes be put into a folder in a subdirectory of my current directory. I.E., if I'm at '.', then the classes could be in './somewhere_else/'

The problem is that when I do this I can't set a value for Main-Class that can find the main class. I have no problem when I build the jar from files at '.', but all the following attempts for main class result in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError's:

```
Main-Class: ClassName
Main-Class: FolderName.ClassName
Main-Class: FolderName/ClassName
```

What should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes inside your jar have to be in the same directory structure as your package structure.

- So, if you want to have your class `ClassName` (without any package) to be the main class, it has to be in the root directory of your jar.
- If you want to have the class in the directory `FolderName`, this same name has to be the package name, meaning the first (non-empty non-comment) line of your source file should be `package FolderName;`.

If your problem is only the build setup - this is not a problem, the folder-layout of your directories outside the jar does not necessarily have to be the same as the layout inside your jar. But it still helps if the folder-structure fits to the package-structure (with maybe additionally directories above).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reference Main-Class simply by the class name (without directory structure). What will help you solve this problem is what you put as the classpath. Make sure the directory of Main-Class is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ClassName` resides in package `FolderName`, then, it should be:-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: FolderName.ClassName
Class-Path: <third-party>.jar <another-third-party>.jar
```

They are case-sensitive, by the way.